# Why does my postgres docker image not contain any data?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'd like to create a docker image with data.

My attempt is as follows:

```
FROM postgres

COPY dump_testdb /image
RUN pg_restore /image
RUN rm -rf /image
```

Then I run `docker build -t testdb .` and `docker run -d testdb`.

When I connect to the container I don't see the restored db. How do I get an image with the restored data?

Answer (score 0):

COPY the dump file, with a `.sql` extension, into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`.  Do not try to RUN anything.  The `postgres` image will run everything in that directory the first time a container is started on a particular data directory.

You generally can’t RUN commands that interact with the database in a Dockerfile because the database won’t be running at that point.  (There is a script in the base image that goes through some complicated gymnastics to do the first-time setup.) In any case, because of the mechanics of Docker’s volume system, you can’t create an image that contains prepopulated database data; you have to use a mechanism like this to cause the image to restore a dump or otherwise set itself up at first start.